# JNI multiple registernatives calls

Tags: android, c++, qt, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Please see the below code snippet.  Basically I have two Java classes that I want to associate native methods with. I switch the jclass object names between "clazz" and "clazz2". Whichever one is set as clazz2 fails to be loaded properly and causes the application to crash because of the missing native calls. Any ideas as to why the second call to RegisterNatives always fails?

To clarify, it works fine with just one jclass pointing to NotificationClient and one registerNatives call.

```
static JNINativeMethod methods[] = {
    {"keyboardVisibleChanged", "(ZIIII)V", (void *)keyboardVisibleChanged},
    {"androidBackPressed", "()V", (void *)androidBackPressed},
    {"activityResultFinished", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", (void *)activityResultFinished},
    {"activityResultTextFinished", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V", (void *)activityResultTextFinished},
    {"activityResultFormFinished", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", (void *)activityResultFormFinished},
    {"activityResultCanceled", "()V", (void *)activityResultCanceled}
};

static JNINativeMethod syncServiceMethods[] = {
    {"blah", "()V", (void *)blah}
};

jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *)
{
    JNIEnv *env;
    if (vm->GetEnv(reinterpret_cast<void **>(&env), JNI_VERSION_1_4) != JNI_OK)
        return JNI_FALSE;

    jclass clazz2 = env->FindClass("org/qtproject/example/notification/NotificationClient");
    jclass clazz = env->FindClass("org/qtproject/example/notification/SyncService");
    env->RegisterNatives(clazz, methods, sizeof(methods) / sizeof(methods[0]));
    env->RegisterNatives(clazz2, syncServiceMethods, sizeof(syncServiceMethods) / sizeof(syncServiceMethods[0]));

return JNI_VERSION_1_4;
}
```

EDIT: When printing out the return values of both `env->RegisterNative` calls, both return 0, which is the same value returned when successfully running the application with just 1 `RegisterNatives` call.

Comment: When you say `static` are you saying that those variables are declared in that file and only that file?  You didn't place the declarations in a header file and included that header file in multiple modules, right?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - I edited my question to show the code as is. The static arrays are both declared in the same .cpp file as JNI_OnLoad

Comment: Why don't you use  the Qt Android Extras module?

Comment: Are you checking the return values from `FindClass` and just not showing them here? How do you know the other calls are succeeding? Can you add the failure message to your question?

Comment: @Nejat I am using the Qt Android Extras module, and I think that may(???) be what is causing the issue since they handle some of the JNI magic for me

Comment: @fadden I am checking the return values, I just left that out of the code to make it simpler to read. I had the statements printing out the return value and they both return 0. if only one is run, which works and doesn't crash, it returns 0 as well.

Comment: wait a sec, when you swap cazz with clazz2, do you also swap the methods with syncServiceMethods? I would expect you only to swap the lines that call RegisterNatives().

Answer (score 0):

Change implementation.

Instead of calling twice, it is called in a loop, when FindClass is not null.